# Is there an explanation for this symmetry of the absolute value metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, real-numbers, absolute-value, symmetry

Consider a metric space $(\mathcal{X}, d)$ and four points $x, y, z, u \in \mathcal{X}$.

When $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}$ and $d(x,x') = |x - x'|$, then the metric has the following interesting property.
There is a perfect matching between the terms $$d(x,y) + d(y,z), \qquad d(x,u) + d(u,z), \qquad d(x,z) + 2 d(y,u)$$ and the terms $$d(x,y) + d(y,u) + d(u,z), \qquad d(x,u) + d(u,y) + d(y,z), \qquad d(x,z)$$ such that the matched terms are equal.
For example, when $x \leq y \leq u \leq z$ then $$d(x,y)+d(y,z) = d(x,z), \quad d(x,u)+d(u,z) = d(x,z), \quad d(x,y) + d(y,u) + d(u,z) = d(x,z), \quad d(x,u) + d(u,y) + d(y,z) = d(x,z) + 2 d(y,u).$$

Intuitively, there is a certain symmetry between $x,y,z,u$ such that the triangle inequality turns into an equality in certain cases.

I am wondering: Is this a peculiar case of $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}$ and $d(x,x') = |x - x'|$ or is there a more general phenomenon that explains this intriguing behavior?

Comment: Your matchings are usually incorrect when $x,y,u,z$ are not in that order. But when they are correct the reason is simply that all points are aligned (in the correct order), since $\mathbb{R}$ is a straight line.

Comment: @CaptainLama I agree, the exact matching that I added as an example will not hold for any ordering. But (unless I missed a case), for any ordering there will be such a matching (it might look slightly different). Did I miss a case?

Comment: Yours is a nice observation. The theoretical reason for it lies in a general, easy fact of normed spaces: if $u, v$ are vectors, and they are such that $v=\lambda u$ for $\lambda>0$, then $$\lVert u+v\rVert = (1+\lambda)\lVert u\rVert=\lVert u\rVert+\lVert v \rVert.$$
In words, when the vectors are positively aligned you have equality in the triangle inequality. Now, on $\mathbb R$ all vectors are aligned (not necessarily positively aligned, of course), so it comes to no surprise that you observe more identities connected with the triangle inequality.